# How to use for and if together in Python

Tags: python

I have a list which has 100 to 1 in decreasing order. I want to print the numbers which are divisible by 25. below code seems rights but doesn't give output.

```
r=range(100,0,-1) #defining the list
print(list(r))    #printing the list
for t in list(r): #loop to traverse through the list
    if(t/25==0):  #condition to check divisibity test
        print(t)  #printing on satisfying the condition
```

I want to see 100, 75, 50, 25 after execution. I am neither getting any output nor any error with my code.

Comment: `if(t%25==0):` ?

Comment: Ew. such silly . Thanks to remind. I am deleting the question.

Comment: Not what you asked but: you don't define the list, you define a range - that's a different thing

Comment: Apart from using modulus you should consider using range directly in your code instead of assigning it to a variable @Satyajeet

Answer (score 3):

The divisibility test is done by using `%` modulus operator, which is `a%b` and it returns 0 if a is divisible by b

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second.

```
r=range(100,0,-1) #defining the list
for t in list(r): #loop to traverse through the list
    if(t%25==0):  #condition to check divisibity test
        print(t)  #printing on satisfying the condition
```

Also you do not need to assign range to a variable and then use it, you can use it directly

```
for t in range(100,0,-1): #loop to traverse through the list
    if(t%25==0):  #condition to check divisibity test
        print(t)  #printing on satisfying the condition
```

Additionally, another approach using list-comprehension might be, (given you might need the list later)

```
li = [item for item in range(100, 0, -1) if item%25 == 0]
print(li)
#[100, 75, 50, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Devesh's answer which is the right one, if you absolutely need a one-liner here's a list comprehension (though note this creates a list of `None`s in the background which is a bit wasteful)

```
_ = [print(t) for t in r if t % 25 == 0]
100
75
50
25
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use list-comprehensions in a function that returns `None` like print, since you are essentially creating a list of size 4 with all elements as none

Comment: Absolutely and hence the list is discarded straight away using `_`. But wanted to share the list comprehension for completeness.

Comment: But why not create a list of valid numbers (divisible by 25) and print it? Also `_` is not discarding, it is just saying that I am not going to use this list, the list is getting created anyways!

Comment: Sure that works especially if you need the list later - just not a one-liner anymore :) let me clarify my answer especially now that you've updated yours with all possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
r=range(100,0,-1) 
#print(list(r))    
for t in list(r): 
    if(t%25==0): 
        print(t)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @DimaKozhevin I'll keep take care of that next time, Thanks